# Passing parameters to system calls

Tags: c, linux, kernel, parameter-passing, system-calls

I did a basic helloWorld system call example that had no parameters and was just:

```
int main()
{
   syscall(__NR_helloWorld);
   return 0;
}
```

But now I am trying to figure out how to pass actual arguments to the system call (ie. a `long`).  What is the format exactly, I tried:

```
int main()
{
   long input = 1;
   long result = syscall(__NR_someSysCall, long input, long);
   return 0;
}
```

Where it takes a `long` and returns a `long`, but it is not compiling correctly; what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the type names. It's just a function call. Example:

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    char str[] = "boo\n";
    syscall( __NR_write, STDOUT_FILENO, str, sizeof(str) - 1 );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1 refers to the # of parameters, but what does 4 refer to?

Comment: No, `1` **is** a parameter - `stdout` file descriptor number in this case, `4` is the length of the buffer, as in `write( FILENO_STDOUT, boo, 4 );`

Answer (score 2):

The prototype for `syscall` is

```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE        /* or _BSD_SOURCE or _SVID_SOURCE */
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <sys/syscall.h>   /* For SYS_xxx definitions */

   int syscall(int number, ...);
```

This says that it takes a variable number (and type) of parameters.  That depends on the particular system call.  `syscall` is not the normal interface to a particular system call.  Those can be explicitly coded, for example `write(fd, buf, len)`.